# Homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

I was working with an exercise of general topology and I had a question: are there an homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}\to(0,1)$ such that $f(x)\in\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$?, i.e., the homeomorphism maps the rationals to rationals and therefore the irrationals to irrationals.

My intuition says that the answer is yes but I can't find an example. The closer example was $g:\mathbb{R}\to(0,1)$ defined by $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+2^{-x}}$. But I think that doesn't works.

Comment: (Yes, I am aware that the question is slightly different, but the answers are similar enough.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x)=(\frac x {1+|x|}+1)/2$ is such a map. Its inverse is $y \to \frac {2y-1} {1-|2y-1|}$.

Comment: how do you show this map is onto? either map that is. 1-1 isn't too bad.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. By a well-known result, any two countable totally-ordered sets
with no largest and smallest elements are order-isomorphic. Therefore
there is an order-isomorphism $F:\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)$. Now $\Bbb R$
and $(0,1)$ can be constructed by Dedekind cuts on $\Bbb Q$ and
$\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)$ respectively. Thus $F$ extends to an order-isomorphism
$f:\Bbb R\to(0,1)$. As both $\Bbb R$ and $(0,1)$ have the topologies
induced by their ordering, $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Wow. Your answer is an overkill to my exercise and is great, but, are there an explicit homeomorphism?

Comment: @CarlosJiménez One can construct a "piecewise-linear" example.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct an example by hand, choosing a rational at each integer (say) and imposing piecewise linearity.

For example, let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to(0,1)$ be
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1-\dfrac1{2(x+1)} & \text{if }x\in\mathbb{N}\\
\dfrac1{2(-1-x)} & \text{if }-x\in\mathbb{N}\\
\frac12 & \text{if }n=0\\
\text{linear} & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$